# Why var result = typeof - "Hello, World"; return a number and not an exception?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any explanation why typeof return number in this example :

```
class MyClass{}

var result = typeof - "Hello, World";
// -----------------^
console.log(result);
// number  -- for me, it's not logic

var result2 = typeof + new MyClass();
// ------------------^
console.log(result2);
// number  -- for me, it's not logic
```

But for this cases :

```
var str = - new MyClass();
// NaN -- why not an exception

var str = - "some strings";
// NaN -- why not an exception

var result2 = typeof -24;
console.log(result2);
// number  -- logic because its a number
```

---

Maybe some cases is logic, but my question is, why typescript return **number** as result in the first and second example, logically the result should be **"object", "undefined", "NaN", or even throw an exception** as it do in this one :

```
var result2 = typeof % 'Hello, World';
```

But not a **number**!

I tried to search in documentation but there are no explanation.

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: Not sure why someone has downvoted your question @YCF_L because it is an intriguing issue.

Comment: Downvoter here. The author appears to have failed to do basic research about what the `typeof` operator does (this is well-documented), speculates about having found a bug in a 20-year-old PL (wat), and is basically asking "Why doesn't JS have more exceptions", which is opinion-based.

Comment: Also really unclear why `+1` and `-1` are legal JS but not `%1` is an intriguing question. Is unary modulus a thing?

Comment: Well modulo operator requires two arguments on both sides of `%`. Not so in the case of `+`/`-`

Comment: I see you're coming from java a strongly typed language. Here in js, let's just say, everything is done on a bit of assumption, which, IMO is better than throwing a bunch of errors on each unexpected operation.

Comment: @TheMaster well said, I'm a newbi in this languages javascript and typescript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = typeof - "Hello, World";
```

The meaning of this code is:

- Apply the unary negation operator `-` to `"Hello, World"`
- The result of this is `NaN`
- Apply the `typeof` operator to the value `NaN`
- The result of this is `"number"`

"Why doesn't JavaScript throw more exceptions?" is a philosophical question that doesn't really have a concrete answer apart from "Its designer thought that would be better"

Comment: To add to this, [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) dictates that the unary minus `-` and `typeof` operators both have the same precedence level, 16.  That level uses right-to-left order, so the unary minus will be evaluated first.

Answer (score 2):

Because `NaN` is a `number`

```js
const nantype = typeof NaN;
console.info(nantype);
```